# Possible to hide Chart.js grid lines that extend beyond chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to find a way of hiding the grid lines that extend beyond the max value of the axis (see image below for reference).

[image]

And the same for the X-Axis of course. I essentially just want the lines to stop at the max tick value. I've scoured the documentation but no avail so hoping the good people of SE will be able to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you using?  My bar chart in v 2.5.0 doesn't extend above

[image: Bar Chart sample]

It does have the optional 'padding' argument:

```
   window.myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: barChartData,
      options: {
        elements: {
          rectangle: {
              borderWidth: 2,
          }
        },
        layout: {
          padding: {
            top: 12
          }
        },
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          position: 'right',
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, layout.padding solved the problem. I was handling the padding with CSS initially but the padding property seems to add white-space, covering the line extensions.

Comment: Your chart has the opposite problem, though, the horizontal gridlines go through the leftmost vertical line